# Share custom Image, Url, Content on Facebook, Twitter, Google plus For Different products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, share

I have a site that have different products . for each product details page I want button for facebook, google plus and twitter . That should share image , url , description of that product.

I googled for custom sharing and tried different codes found from different documentation, but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have different image for each page. We would need to set the facebook meta-tags of that page to refer to the image you mentioned. When I had to add this to one of my clients, i used the sharable gem `https://github.com/hermango/shareable` as it made integration easier and on each page I placed the following facebook share tag.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= image_url(product.url) %>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= product.title %>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<%= product_url %>"/>
```

There are similar meta-tags for twitter as well. This would help you place custom image for each product you share.